# Buildroot clean my dependencies after change my source code

Tags: c++, configuration, buildroot

Im using buildroot to make a custom linux image, and it is working.

The problem is when i run "make" to finish the image after change my package "source code", because it cleans my custom package dependencies and all header include are not found.

I have a dependency with structure:

```
################################################################################
#
# hello
#
################################################################################

HELLO_VERSION = 1.0
HELLO_SITE = ./package/hello/src
HELLO_SITE_METHOD = local
HELLO_DEPENDENCIES += directfb libogg libvorbis mpg123 sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_gfx sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer sdl2_net

define HELLO_BUILD_CMDS
    $(MAKE) CC="$(TARGET_CC)" CXX="$(TARGET_CXX)" LD="$(TARGET_LD)" -C $(@D)
endef

define HELLO_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)/hello $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin
    mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)/opt/app
    cp -r $(@D)/assets $(TARGET_DIR)/opt/app
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

When i run **"make hello-rebuild && make"**, i got error that all SDL includes don't exists.

When i got this error i rebuild only the dependencies packages with "make sdl2-rebuild", "make sdl2_mixer-rebuild", etc.

Can anyone help me understand how i can solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After post in other places the same answer, a buildroot user answer with correct way, that is use @STAGING directory when compile instead of @TARGET directory.

In my makefile i compile it using @TARGET_DIR/usr/[folder], but the correct is @STAGING_DIR/usr[folder].

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is enough to remove your `output/build/hello-1.0` folder and type `make` again

Buildroot used to use stamp files in the output folder, which indicates which targets have been built. removing these files may allow you to rebuild parts of your image without much overhead.